# Get values of deployed images helm/kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I'm looking for an easy way to find what version of my images I have deployed in my kubernetes environment.

The closest thing I can find to what I want is `helm get values <namespace> -a` 

(but this gets values and dumps all (computed) values)

Is there an easier/clean way to get a list of images and versions deployed??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o yaml | grep image: | cut -d ":" -f2,3 | sort | uniq
```

this command shows all images used in your cluster and removes the duplicates.

Comment: Hi @LouisBaumann, could you please add more detail to your answer?

Comment: the command is just straight forward... get all pods in the cluster an print them as yaml then grep only the lines containing image: and then split every line on ":" and use only the second and third part of the line (first is "image") then sort the output and remove the duplicates.

do you need some more details?

Comment: The cut part of your command seems to throw the following error `cut: only one type of list may be specified`

Comment: `kubectl get pods -A -o json | jq -r '.items[].spec.containers[].image' | sort -u`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `kubectl` to get all images form all pods running in the namespace/cluster. See [List All Container Images Running in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/).

For one namespace:

```
kubectl get pods -n <namespace> -o jsonpath="{..image}" | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

For the whole cluster:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}" | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helm plugin - `helm images`.

URL: https://github.com/nikhilsbhat/helm-images

```
    Usage:
  images get [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
```